# How to stop Python while running?

Tags: python

I'm going to the programming competition and I need help. How do I stop a program while code is running? I tried the sys. exit () or only exit () but it doesn't work as I imagined. Here's the beginning of the code, so if anyone can help me, please answer.
Thanks in future.
Here is beginning of code:
K = Int (input ())
J = Int (input ())

If K is < 9 or K, 11:
    Exit ()

If K is < 14 or K, 16:
    Exit ()

Comment: tried to google "python exit script" yet? You could have solved this question by yourself.

Comment: I think this is asking how a user who is *running* a program can stop the program. Typing code in the language the program is written in while *running* a program written in that language--such as typing `exit()` while running a Python program--does not work to quit the program (except in some very strange situations). @karel's answer explains what can be done instead. If that's what this is asking, then it's on-topic for Ask Ubuntu and should be reopened (though perhaps reclosed as a duplicate). Aleksa Radovic, I recommend that you **[edit]** this question to clarify if this is what you mean.

Answer (score 2):

The code in your question has numerous errors, so let's start with Python code that prints the numbers between 1 and 10 at 5 second intervals between printing each number and then exits.

```py
import time
i = 1
while True:  
    print(i)  
    i = i + 1
    time.sleep(5)  
    if(i > 10):  
        break
```

The above code will take almost a minute to finish executing unless it is interrupted before it is finished. To exit from a program before it is finished press the key combination <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>

Results of pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>:

```
^CTraceback (most recent call last):
  File "print-1-to-10.py", line 6, in <module>
    time.sleep(5)  
KeyboardInterrupt
``
```